# How to make a default value in lookup using Lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components

I created a custom lookup field in contact object using LWC by referring this blog
https://lwcfactory.com/custom-lookup-salesforce-lwc/

I want to display a Account Name inside that lookup field which will be a default value.

Answer (score 1):

1. Pass the **default-record-id** attribute with the Id of the default record you want to set in c-custom-lookup-lwc component with the valid Object API Name of the record.

Comment: "default-record-id "     use this

Comment: Use the     ---> s-object-api-name="Account"  on the c-custom-lookup-lwc and then default-record-id="recordId"